# How to display an image using Julia

Tags: image

I am using Julia in Atom on a MacBookPro
I am trying to use ImageView.imshow() to visualize images and whatever the image i try to visualize I get an ImageView window which is entirely white.
What am I doing wrong?
Here are the few lines on REPL that I use :

```
using ImageView
using Images
using TestImages
img = testimage("mandrill")
ImageView.imshow(img)
```

Comment: add exceptions/errors thrown, if any.  search for any png or jpg or gif files in your system. verify whether the following works: img = load("/obsolute/path/to/image"); imshow(img); if no exceptions/errors.

Comment: There is no problem to view an image in the Plot Pane. The problem is to view the image in an external window using ImageView and ImageView.imshow(), in the same way it is possible to view plots in an external window using PyPlot

Comment: verify binaries of zlib, imagemagick, png, jpg, gif etc are avaialable at shell prompt.. if not, configure like $export LD_LIBRARY=/opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/share/julia/stdlib/v1.1/ImageMagick/deps/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH